# edit posts through front-end

Tags: editor, front-end

It's possible to insert posts by users through the front-end by using plugins such as gravity forms or by using wp_insert_post. However, how would one handle the editing of those posts? This has to be in a safe/foolproof/secure way for users.

Comment: Yup, I'd love to see an answer to this too. I've got a nice complex wp_insert_post form on a wine rating site. Allows featured image to be set, additional images uploaded, etc. And use of custom field sfor ratings, etc. But I haven't been able to get proper editing going. I've seen a site using a large amount of jquery which handles this, but I don't know jQuery that well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[WP User Frontend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/)** and **[Post From Site](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-from-site/)** plugins (among others) allow users to create and edit posts from the front-end.

I am sure you can find a lot more — [try this](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20create%20post%20from%20front-end).

Answer (score -3):

What's the context or design purpose of the site?  Is it a community with multiple authors or a team site?  It might not be what you're looking for but you can enable users to post quick entries and replies, kind like a Twitter stream via [the P2 theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/p2).  It is very, very simple but might work for you.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not going down that road, as it's not twitter related and I already heavily developed it :) That being said, it's crowd-sourced, so multiple authors, which should only be allowed to edit their own posts.

Comment: This theme isn't Twitter related, just constructed so it appears like a comment stream.  Why don't you just look at the code and see if you can pull the post form from the theme and re-use it for the theme you've built?  Obviously it IS possible, so starting with the P2 homepage code should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi James, I already have the functionality of creating new posts, I need to find a way to allow editing new posts.